# File I/O not being executed in windows C++ service

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, service

I wrote a simple Windows C++ service (Visual Studio 2012), which starts, listens on a port and also prints log messages to a file.

This is the startup code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "MyHeader.h"

int main()
{
    if(!InitAndStartService())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Within `InitAndStartService`, I call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` and open my logging file writing a couple of messages to it.

The problem I'm facing is that the file is never created. The file I/O logic is written using `CreateFile` and `WriteFile`.

I even tried putting in the following code snippet in the `main` right before the if condition:

```
FILE *file = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
char *str = "hi";
fwrite((void *)str, 1, strlen(str), file);
fclose(file);
```

But the file is still not created. I had also put in a check such that if the file handle returned from `fopen` was NULL, I'd directly exit without going into `InitAndStartService` so that the SCM would give an error. But it turns out that the file handle isn't null.

The service does start and stop properly, but I don't see the port being open using `netstat` while it is running. The service is running as Local System, and has the required permissions to write to the folder.

What could be the reasons for this behaviour, and how can I dig further into this ?

Comment: Do you know from which directory your service is ran from? `temp.txt` will be in that directory. You could try to fully specify the path (for example `"C:\\temp.txt"`) and see how it goes.

Comment: @jules: Your idea is in fact a possible explanation why it doesn't work. You probably don't have write permission in the root dir.

Comment: @Cygnus: you said "required permissions to write to **the** folder", but which folder are you referring to?

Comment: Okay, I tried putting it to a different drive. And it worked!!!!!
I believed the service had the required permissions to write to the folder where I was creating the file. Wouldn't Local System have that ?

Comment: So I don't have permissions to write anywhere in C:. What could be the reasons ?

Comment: Check the SID type.  You can do this from the command line with `sc qsidtype`